# Subclassing DynamicObject in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've been testing out some of the new stuff in VS 2010 and C# 4.0, and been pushing at things a little to see the limits of it, and so far I like what I see, but one thing has me slightly annoyed...

Given the following two simple classes, is there some way (other than calling `TryGetMember` directly) to avoid the cast to `dynamic`? Perhaps some magic attribute that can be set on `Test`?

```
class DynamicPropertyObject : DynamicObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        foreach (string s in _properties.Keys)
            yield return s;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _properties[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (!_properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            return false;

        result = _properties[binder.Name];
        return true;
    }
}

class Test : DynamicPropertyObject
{
    public Test()
    {
        ((dynamic)this).Foo = "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need the cast to `dynamic` so that the compiler can convert the property access into a `TryGetMember` class.

Edit:

Since .NET and C# are not exactly dynamic nor intended to always be late bound (except for virtual members), it is necessary to explicitly state that you want dynamic typing when you do. There is no in-between: a statically typed object var which acts as dynamically typed when the compiler cannot find the member at compile-time.

Comment: Yea, you do... Was wondering if perhaps there was some way to tell the compiler that this class should be treated dynamically since it's apparently not 'smart' (I'm sure there's reasons for it) enough to realise that something that subclasses DynamicObject can be treated as a dynamic anywhere.

Comment: There's no specific reason why class subclassing `DynamicObject` should suddenly be treated differently. For one thing, any class can be "treated as dynamic anywhere". For another, treating a class as dynamic changes call semantics, and your class may well have some (non-dynamic) members for which this may have a difference. Therefore the rule is simple and always requires `dynamic`.

Comment: A variable typed as DynamicObject (or a derived class) is a statically typed one - thus it cannot be treated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic attribute to force a class always be treated as if it was `dynamic`. However, if your problem is specifically that you want it for `this` inside the class, just add a helper property:

```
private dynamic DynThis { get { return this; } }
```

and use it instead.

Comment: The specific problem was that I was hoping to get around needing the `this` part at all. Yes, I know it changes call semantics, but one would imagine (disclaimer: I know only a bare minimum about how this actually works) that the compiler could examine the call at compile-time, if it doesn't point at a solid member of the class, and the class is subclassed from `DynamicObject`, which means it explicitly supports dynamic calls made against it, then it could emit a runtime dynamic call instead.